# how to intercept WM_QUIT in powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I have to maintain a system composed of a master application (a control panel) which starts/ stops ancillary applications on demand. The ancillary applications are run as separate processes and according to the documentation, when the master wants them to stop, it send them a WM_QUIT signal and if the application don't stop, it kills the process.

One of the ancillary application is a powershell script that runs window-less. Is there a way to intercept WM_QUIT in powershell? I googled for an event to register with `Register-ObjectEvent` but found nothing.

for now, the system runs on windows 2008-R2 + Powershell v2 but if necessary I may upgrade to Windows 2012-R2 + Powershell v5.

Comment: WM_QUIT requires that you have a window. WM = window Message.  The window can be hidden if you want, but you need a window.  Are trying to just listen for the event or are you trying to stop the event from happening?

Answer (score 0):

This will make a hidden form.  It will listen if WM_quit is sent to it.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '400,400'
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$Form.Visible                    = $false

$Form.Add_Load({ test })

Function test () {
# Start Writing your code here
# This hidden Window will receive your WM_Quit
# Since your code is part of the form it will stop when WM_Quit is sent.
}
```

Comment: I did some testings. the Visible property is not taken into account and the window must be created out of the screen, the onLoad procedure is not executed as long as the window is not instantiated by an [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($Form), the events are not checked during the execution of the onLoad code, and once the application.run has been called, the script can do nothing else. but I got the idea and was able able to make my script WM_QUIT aware.